# Missing storeId parameter in proposeedit endpoint

Tags: foursquare

With deprecating /edit endpoint in favor of /proposeedit, what should I use for updating venue's storeId? It's seems that it's missing from parameters list.

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/proposeedit

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/edit

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint should still accept this parameter if you're the venue manager as the `storeId` is designed for the manager of a venue (and is only visible to them). If you need help bulk updating storeIds for venues that you manage you should probably reach out to https://enterprise.foursquare.com/contact-us